# Vue 3 get value from function @click event to use to calculate some math. - typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vite

I'm making a tip calculator using vuejs 3 and typescript. I have 5 buttons with some values, I want to use their values to calculate a total, how do call the function tipPercentage so that it gives me  a single numerical value which I can use to calculate the total, and also I can't add bill since it's a Ref type and not a number type.
I'm using vue 3.2 script setup and typescript, open to javascript solution
[image of tip calculator app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPTje.jpg)

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
let tips = [
  { id: 1, percent: 5},
  { id: 2, percent: 10},
  { id: 3, percent: 15},
  { id: 4, percent: 25},
  { id: 5, percent: 50},
]
 const bill: number  = ref(0)
let  tipPercentageValue = (percentValue: number) => percentValue
const total: number = bill+ bill*tipPercentageValue(percentValue)
</script>
```

```html
<h3>Bill</h3>
   <input class="bill-input" type="number" v-model="bill" placeholder="enter bill" />
    <h3>Select Tip %</h3>
        <div class="tip-percent-buttons" >
          <button  class="percent-btn" v-for="tip in tips" :key="tip.id" @click="tipPercentageValue(tip.percent)" :value="tip.percent">
            {{ tip.percent }}%
          </button>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems in your code with the usage of `ref`. If you use the ref in your `<script>` and you want to assign a new value you need to add `.value`
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#creating-standalone-reactive-values-as-refs

Furthermore your `tipPercantageValue`function does nothing.

```
  const selectedPercentage = ref(0)
  const total = ref(0)

  function percentageSelected(percentage: number) {
    selectedPercentage.value = percentage
    total.value = bill.value+ bill.value*selectedPercentage.value
  }
```

like this `total` and `bill`are reactive. Then use the `percentageSelected`function as the `@click`function

if you want the percentage to be in the 'correct' format add `const computedPercantage = computed(() => selectedPercentage.value/100)` and use it like

```
function percentageSelected(percentage: number) {
    selectedPercentage.value = percentage
    total.value = bill.value+ bill.value*computedPercantage.value
  }
```

Comment: I will add that if you need to specify types for ref, then you can write like this:
 `const selectedPercentage = ref<number>(0);`